# VBox condensing elements

Tags: java, javafx

My problem is when I'm dynamically adding elements to a VBox, the elements get closer together as I add more elements to the VBox. Is there any way to stop this from happening?
Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would not a `TableView` better fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments already, you can use the `setSpacing()` and `setFillWidth()` methods to adjust how the VBox spaces it's contents.

**Example:**

```
public class MCVE extends Application {

   public void start(Stage stage) {
      VBox vbox = new VBox();
      vbox.setSpacing(15.0);


      int ct = 0;
      Text text;
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         String textString = "Item " + ct++;
         text = new Text(textString);

         vbox.getChildren().add(text);
      }

      stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 400, 400));
      stage.show();

   }

}
```